# Запись видео с ip камер на Centos

Tags: vlc, камера, centos

Добрый день!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как через vlc записывать видео с ip камеры и чтобы файлы делись по часу записи. Centos установлен minimal. ip камеры - 4 штуки. В linux системах разбираюсь просто еще слабовато, и вот никак не могу разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

вопрос, собственно, не имеет практически никакого отношения к операционной системе.

нужные для записи параметры должны быть изложены в документации к программе `vlc`. и зависят они **в первую очередь** от того, каким образом ip-камеры отдают поток, т.е., фактически, от моделей камер и их настроек.